NoSuchKey error when deleting django-avatar file saved on DigitalOcean Spaces
I recently upgraded and older Django project to Django 4.2 using the DigitalOcean App Platform. Everything seemed to go fairly smoothly except when trying to delete items managed by the django-avatar package, where the avatar images are stored on DO Spaces (S3 object storage). Saving images using django-storages with boto3 to handle the s3 objects still works fine, however, when deleting items through the admin ui it throws the following:
NoSuchKey at /admin/avatar/avatar/37/delete/
An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the ListObjects operation: None
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost/admin/avatar/avatar/37/delete/
Django Version: 4.2.9
Exception Type: NoSuchKey
Exception Value:    
An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the ListObjects operation: None
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py, line 964, in _make_api_call
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.options.delete_view
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.10.14
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages']

After reviewing every SO issue that could be related to this for django-avatar (8.0), boto3 (1.34), and DO Spaces issues, I haven't come up with anything that points me in the right direction.
I have verified the key exists and it also has no issues displaying the avatar images. This error appears to be coming from botocore, but attempting to delete other images and files (media or static files) stored with the same backend storage doesn't have any problems; it's only when attempting to delete the avatars managed by by django-avatar. If I roll back django-avatar to an older version that was working (5.0), it works fine, but that version and dependencies are no longer supported.
I'm not sure what other areas I may be overlooking. Any thoughts or things to explore would be greatly appreciated.

I've narrowed this down to this being related to how django storages is configured  on Django >= 4.2 and how AVATAR_CLEANUP_DELETED is set to True by default. I'll follow up once I get a working configuration settled, but for now, setting AVATAR_CLEANUP_DELETED = False doesn't cause django-avatar to throw in the admin area. Just need to keep in mind avatars will then need to be deleted from the s3 bucket in some other way.
